# Hamburger/Drawer dropdown menu that can be used in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, menu, xamarin.forms

I want to avoid implementing a hamburger drop down menu in all three platforms iOS, Android and Windows.  Xamarin Forms is great for cross platform app dev but I cant find all the features I need.  The current feature is this hamburger drop down menu.  I tried using MasterDetailPage, the behaviour is more of a fly in side menu which is not the same but it is great as its own thing.  This works well by itself.  After adding a few more pages and a TabbedPage the UX starts getting clunky.  The fly in menu appears inside the current tabbed view underneath the tabs which looks terrible.  At the moment I do not have a solution for this feature.

Comment: Hey did you get a solution for this? I too, am facing trouble with the menu sliding in from beneath the Tabbed Page.

Comment: No solution is available so we implemented our own hamburger menu.  Use Grid, ScrollView, AbsoluteLayout etc.  Much pain.  We stopped using tabbed Page.

Comment: Ok, so there's no solution to this yet I am guessing but I did figure something else out regarding this. In Android, when you add tabs to you Actionbar, the behavior is exactly what you have mentioned. Xamarin replicates this behavior when creating tabs inside Master/Detail views. I wish there was some way to control this :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a drop-down menu on iOS would be a popover, however that is only available on iPads and not on iPhones. So you'd have to implement your own drop-down solution anyhow. However, if you are OK with using the sidemenu that is implemented by Xamarin Forms by default, you could make your hierarchy like this:

MasterDetailPage:

- Master : your dropdown view
- Detail: your TabbedPage

I believe this should sort out your problem.

Comment: Already tried MasterDetail + TabbedPage and demo'd to my team who all agreed its clunky and not fit for a professional app.  Finding a solution the works perfectly on all platforms seems impossible atm.  Might have to add multiple implementations for each platform, not looking forward to that.